# Ubuntu Core and Docker like networking

Tags: networking, snap, docker, ubuntu-core, container

Does Ubuntu Core and Snaps (containers) allow for the flexibility that Docker networking allows, such as:

- default docker bridge
- user defined bridge
- deploying containers to host networking
- MACVLANs (MAC address virtual local area networks)/ switch like
- IPVLANs / router like
- overlay networks
- none networks

A very good example and the ease of use & flexibility of adding and removing containers as part of networks is shown by example by NetworkChuck: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKFMS5C4CG0

Otherwise, if I install Docker Snap (sudo snap install docker) would all my Docker containers be deployed within this one Docker Snap allowing for all the networking customization to function?

Answer (score 1):

Snaps are NOT a flavor of containerization.

Snaps are merely a form of software packaging that include AppArmor rule-based sandboxing and other fancy designs for robustness, security, and safety. They generally do not use cgroups (except for snaps that *include* containers, of course).

---

"*[I]f I install Docker Snap (sudo snap install docker) would all my Docker containers be deployed within this one Docker Snap allowing for all the networking customization to function?*"

Close. The docker snap is the docker hypervisor. Your containers will be installed by (not in) that hypervisor. Yes, your custom networking will be implemented by the hypervisor.